# Getting Bad Request - 400 when sending dynamic JSON data to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

[Sending dynamic JSON data to Azure Log Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnEdT.png)

We have 1 logic app which is sending data to Custom Log Analytics when we are sending that data in eventBody column then we are getting "Bad Request error".

```
"eventBody":{
      "values":[
         {
            "metricCategory":"FILE",
            "metricSubcategory":"VARIABLE",
            "metricSubsubcategory":"XML Value",
            "id":"%ATOPATH% DATA AlohaToGoConfig.xml",
            "unit":"1",
            "valueString":"Unknown"
         }
      ]
   }

{
"RunID": "0858512362441",
"aliasName": "Firehouse",
 "applicationName": "PulseAgent.PulseStreamingMetricsCollector",
 "applicationVersion": "21",
 "caseAssignedGroup": "DCS",
 "caseAssignee": "Pulse",
 "caseITSMTool": "TEST",
 "caseId": "",
 "caseNotes": "Action",
"caseQueueName": "00G4u000",
 "caseStatus": "New",
 "caseSummary": "Summary description of the incident",
 "computerName": "AL",
 "countryCode": "US",
 "deviceId": "0",
 "eventBody": "{"values":[{"metricCategory":"FILE","metricSubcategory":"VARIABLE","metricSubsubcategory":"XML Value","id":"%ATOPATH%\\DATA\\AlohaToGoConfig.xml","unit":"1","valueString":"Unknown"}]}",
 "eventCategory": "XML Value",
 "eventStatus": "0",
 "eventSubcategory": "%ATOPATH%\DATA\AlohaToGoConfig.xml",
"fua": "407",
"mcn":  "4128",
 "messageType": "MET",
 "organizationId": "fs",
 "siteId": "37",
 "timeUtc": "2023-07-13T10:34:05.1303265Z"
}
```

Any help will be really helpful and let me know if further details are required.

JSON Request Body:

If i update eventBody with generic value apart from JSON then no error is coming.

Expecting that without error eventBody gets stored in Azure Log Analytics table

Comment: Basically I wanted to know how to pass JSON object in a string variable :  "eventBody": "{"values":[{"metricCategory":"FILE","metricSubcategory":"VARIABLE","metricSubsubcategory":"XML Value","id":"%ATOPATH%\\DATA\\AlohaToGoConfig.xml","unit":"1","valueString":"Unknown"}]}",
As this is giving Bad Request error

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced this issue at my environment by making few modification in the data and it worked for me***

**`Input Data`**

Here I have taken RunID and EventBody only but you can add other attributes as well.

[image]

**`Output`**

**Please Note** I have changed the Id attribute value from
`%ATOPATH%\\DATA\\AlohaToGoConfig.xml` to `%ATOPATH%/DATA/AlohaToGoConfig.xml` , as taking forward slash is giving Data format error while sending data to log analytics workspace.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details but what I was looking for is how to pass JSON as a string in a log analytics variable. Formatting of data is fine but what i was receiving is a dynamic eventBody JSON, so I dont want to parse it and get it directly stored in a string variable

Comment: You need to parse the data in order to get it into proper data format as per logic app or else you will get data format error, while reproducing I tried every possible way but seems like log analytics is not accepting it